# mkvmerge equivalent code in python using Pymkv to add subtitles to a mp4 video

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a vid.mp4 file and a subs.srt (subtitles file) I can use mkvmerge on Linux to create a new mkv file with subtitles like this:

```
mkvmerge -o newmkv.mkv vid.mp4 subs.srt
```

How to do the same using Pymkv module (wrapper for mkvmerge)? I tried this:

```
import pymkv
mkv = pymkv.MKVFile()
mkv.add_track('vid.mp4')
mkv.add_track('subs.srt')
mkv.mux('newmkv.mkv')
```

newmkv.mkv file is created with subtitles but sound is gone. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you add the mp4 file `add_track` only adds the first track of the file, only the video, you need to add the audio in another track and specify the `track_id`

```
mkv.add_track(pymkv.MKVTrack('vid.mp4', track_id=1))
```

Usually the Audio track is 1, but you better validate with `mkvmerge -J vid.mp4`